# Parsing XML with PHP - Error: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl, simplexml

Preface: I searched and read thoroughly before posting this question.  I saw a few questions similar to mine, some even with the same error message, but most of them had simple answers, such as "need a single root element."  I have been unable to apply those solutions here, hence I am posting.

I am using PHP and cURL to consume a .NET web service, wherein I send data in XML format, and receive a response, also in XML format.  It is working correctly and I have verification of a good write on the .NET service end.  When I use:

```
$xml_obj = simplexml_load_string($result);
print $xml_obj->asXML()
```

the response XML returns to the browser as such:

[image]

I am attempting to parse that XML so that I can do something meaningful with the potential errors, and / or the successful response.  I am trying to use this method:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_obj);
$is = $xml->xpath('*/i');

foreach($is as $i) {
    echo $i['title'], ': ', $i['description'], "\n";
}
```

which may or may not be the best approach.  When I execute this, I receive this message:

[image]

It is unclear to me whether the problem is in the response XML (which the error message seems to indicate, but I am unable to find), or if I am attempting to parse the XML in an incorrect manner.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've tried every variation I can think to try it, and have tried every method of parsing this XML, with no results.  The errors persist.  Can anyone out there offer some enlightenment?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix plain text output with XML output. You need to use one or the other.

**Plain Text Output:**

```
foreach($is as $i) {
    echo $i['title'], ': ', $i['description'], "\n";
}
```

View the source of the resulting page and you will clearly see the malformed (plain text) response.

If you are outputting XML, I would expect something more like:

```
foreach($is as $i) {
    echo '<title>', $i['title'], '</title><description>', $i['description'], '</description>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that, but, unfortunately, still receive the same error message.

Comment: This answer made a lot of assumptions and is therefore incomplete. As such, it won't fix your problem directly. It is aimed at identifying your root problem.